# Return a defined range from a different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets, sheetA and sheetB. SheetB is filled with data across rows and columns.

What I am trying to do is for example:
SheetA: fill cells A1:CV1 with values from sheetB cells C251:C350

On sheetA I have a column with all locations of the first cell on sheetB (in this example C251), and for every row would like to return that value + 100 or so columns to the right.

Basically looking for a function that returns the same as just doing =C251 and then fill a number of cells to the right (=C252, =C253 ... =C350)

Comment: What exactly do you have in A1:A100 on SheetA?

Comment: Sorry my bad, meant to be A1:CV1, on sheetA its empty cells, the values i am trying to get from sheetB are numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select A1:CV1, which you can easily do by entering the reference in the Name box to the left of the formula bar.

Enter this formula in the formula bar and commit it with CTRL+ENTER.

```
=INDEX(SheetB!$C$251:$C$350, COLUMN())
```